# Issues with trying to parse JSON into a dictionary

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

when I am trying to convert this JSON string into a Python dictionary, I keep getting an invalid escape error. Below is the code, and the traceback. This is for use with an API that sends out much much more information than this, but this is what I have reduced it down to while maintaining the same error. I have used both \\ and \ inside of this string and get the same result.

```
import json 

work_orders_inprogress = '''
{
    "ItemCollection": [
        {
            "Header": {
                "ID": "work_orderID",
                "CreationTime": "2021-03-17T12:12:47.02-04:00",
                "DeletionTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "DeletionTimeSpecified": true,
                "LastModifiedTime": "2021-10-29T12:12:23.73-04:00",
                "LastModifiedBy": "Mit_rando.Province\\First Last"
            },
            "ID": "work_orderID",
            "Type": "WorkOrder",
            "ScheduledTime": "2021-03-19T12:06:00.937-04:00",
            "PromisedTime": "2021-06-01T19:00:00-04:00",
            "InvoiceTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "WorkOrderNumber": 35659,
            "InvoiceNumber": 0,
            "PurchaseOrderNumber": "",
            "Contact": {
                "Header": {
                    "ID": "work_orderID",
                    "CreationTime": "2021-03-09T13:00:06.77-05:00",
                    "DeletionTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "DeletionTimeSpecified": true,
                    "LastModifiedTime": "2021-08-30T15:21:28.25-04:00",
                    "LastModifiedBy": "Mit_rando.province\\First Last"
                },
                "ID": "work_orderID",
                "FileAs": "Business - CASH CUSTOMER",
                "Name": {
                    "Title": "Manager",
                    "Prefix": "",
                    "FirstName": "First",
                    "MiddleName": "",
                    "LastName": "Last",
                    "Suffix": ""
                },
                "Address": {
                    "Title": "Business",
                    "ID": "work_orderID",
                    "Street": "some random st",
                    "City": "cityname",
                    "Province": "XX",
                    "PostalCode": "XXXXX",
                    "Country": "USA"
                },
                "Company": "Company Name - CASH CUSTOMER",
                "Phone1Title": "Business",
                "Phone1": "(720) fakenumber",
                "Phone2Title": "Cell",
                "Phone2": "(303) fakenumber",
                "EmailTitle": "Email",
                "Email": "fake@email.org",
                "PreferredContactMethod": "Email",
                "MarketingSource": "",
                "Note": "",
                "NoMessaging": false,
                "NoEmail": false,
                "NoPostCard": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(work_orders_inprogress)

print(type(data))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 70, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 11 column 54 (char 386)
```

I have even tried running this on online compilers and get the same result. Thanks!

Comment: So, the problem is that `"\"` is an escape sequence for Python literals, so you are ending up with a string like `"Mit_rando.Province\First Last"` which will not be a valid escape seqeunce for JSON, so you either want something like `"Mit_rando.Province\\\\First Last"` or use a raw string for the Python string literal (probably easiest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the backslashes. Try to take the raw string:

```
work_orders_inprogress = r'''...
```

Comment: adding one more point to the answer, true and false should be True and False in python.

Comment: @VimalanE it's *JSON*. Where it should be `true` and `false`, it will not be valid JSON if they are capitalized

Comment: title says needed to be converted to python dictionary, I can see few boolean values in json which is true and false when converted either it should be a string or python boolean right ?

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! Do you have some documentation you would reccomend reading?

Comment: @VimalanE, that is not correct. true in JSON, will be converted to True when making a python dictionary from json data.

Comment: @VimalanE you're right that a boolean takes value `True` or `False`in Python. However, like others have pointed out, we are reading a json here and the json module ensures that values are correctly interpreted in python. Try `print(data["ItemCollection"][0]["Contact"]["NoEmail"])` from OP's code